# Edit access by checking the field?

Tags: users

Is it possible to check the privileges for a particular field? For example, I have a field in the material `field_access` associated with the user who accepts an ID of the user. How to check access to edit the material through it? Currently editing is possible only if the user specified in the authors. 
(Google translate. Sorry for that)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for this module : [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: Nope. I have this one. I need to CHECK permissons to edit node (EDIT link in post)

Comment: Try https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess then if its for node permissions

Comment: thx, but it's absolutely not what i need. this module check user role. but i need to check user id from specific field. something like this `if ($field_access == $auth_user_id) return $form["edit"]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) is the module you are looking for.

> This is great if you want your content authors to be able to choose additional authors, or choose who can view their content, as well as being able to display the list of authors or viewers within your content, or in views displays.

Comment: hm. maybe. i'll try it. thx

Comment: Did this module help you?